# IllegalStateException: Could not find method showPopup(View)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-cardview, popupmenu

Here's my card view activity where three dots are there as in toolbar and I want to overflow it with menu but getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method showPopup(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'img_menu'

**Here's XML** :

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/card_view"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="80dp"

    android:layout_margin="5dp"

    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"

    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"

    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView2"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"/>

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/img_menu"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_more_vert"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

            android:onClick="showPopup"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Here's activity** :

```
   public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

 private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private static String LOG_TAG = "CardViewActivity";

    ImageButton overflowMenu;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_view);

        overflowMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_menu);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {

            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        }


    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:

                onBackPressed();

                return true;



            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }

    public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.card_overflow_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.one:
                    //Or Some other code you want to put here.. This is just an example.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Clicked 1 " + " : " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.two:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked 2 " + " : " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });


    }


 /*   public void showPopup(View v) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(CardViewActivity.this, v);

        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();


        inflater.inflate(R.menu.card_overflow_menu,popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener((PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener) {

        public boolean onMenuClick (MenuItem item){


        }




    popup.show();

}}*/


    /*public void showMenu(View v) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);

        // This activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener((PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener) 
this);

        popup.inflate(R.menu.card_overflow_menu);

        popup.show();

    }*/


    @Override

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter
                .MyClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);

            }

        });

    }

    private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {

        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

        for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {

            DataObject obj = new DataObject("Test " + index,

                    "Doc number " + index);

            results.add(index, obj);

        }

        return results;

    }



}
```

**LogCat** :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method showPopup(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'img_menu'
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20101)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: You have the `showPopup()` method commented out. Un-comment it.

Comment: used showpopup() before also but facing same issue. can you please tell me how to?  i have used this link   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#groups

Comment: @mdDroid Do _not_ remove content from code when you edit.

Comment: Then we need to see your stack trace - the errors in your logcat - when you run it with the `showPopup()` method un-commented.

Comment: added showpopup() again just as in above link i have given. in activity. still giving error. also provided the complete stack trace here. please have a look.

Comment: I don't see a complete stack trace anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining onClick event on ImageButton, plus you are setting onClickListener on it too.

Use either

`public void showPopup(View v)`

code or

```
 overflowMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

I suggest you to comment out your `overFlowMenu clickListener` code.

Comment: i have updated the code and added stack trace also. also want to use switch case inside menuclick but getting error

Comment: @piyush_droid Did you try what I suggested ?

Comment: yes, i used as in google.developers i.e. showpopup()

Comment: @piyush_droid If you dont wanna use showPopup code and just want to show the toast inside onOptionsItemSelected then comment out showPopup code and from xml delete onClick attribute of ImageButton.

Comment: Actually i was using toast to check whether its working or not. have to add switch case inside of it to show menuitems.

Comment: @piyush_droid You are performing click event on imageButton at two places without any condition, which is wrong. So either remove onclick attribute from xml or remove R.id.img_menu from onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: please have a look on edited showpopup and removed img_menu from onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: @piyush_droid I dont see removed img_menu from onOptionsItemSelected in above code.

Comment: cleaned and added. please have a look

Comment: @piyush_droid Good for you :)